# How to protect and unprotect a sheet using password?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet named "Input" and a button named "unlock". The sheet "Input" must be locked as soon as one opens the workbook. To unlock "input", one must click on the "Unlock" button and then type in the password. The "unlock" button is not present on the "input" sheet

Comment: So where is the button?  The code is fairly simple: `Worksheet.Unprotect`

Answer (score 0):

**Without a password:**

```
Sheet1.Unprotect
'do stuff
Sheet1.Protect
```

**With a password:**

```
Sheet1.Unprotect "123" 'with 123 as a password
'do stuff
Sheet1.Protect "123"
```

`Sheet1` is in this case a codename, which are static so are not subject to change (either by worksheet index or -name). I suggest you find out the codename sheet "Input" and use this opposed to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")` or `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`.

Comment: @rithwiksarma has this helped you?